# Filtering /etc/passwd to only show regular users

Tags: linux, ubuntu

when trying to display the following file

> etc/passwd

Is there a way to just show regular users that would login and have a home directory instead of all these pseudo-users that seem to be part of system processes.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash 
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mike:x:1000:1000:mike,,,:/home/mike:/bin/bash <-- THIS ONE HAS A HOME DIRECTORY
```

Thanks

Aiden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could ask for all accounts that have home directories in `/home`:

```
awk -F: '$6 ~ /\/home/ {print}' /etc/passwd
```

Some systems keep system accounts below a specific user id, so you can ask for all accounts with UIDs higher than some limit:

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 {print}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Wicked. I'm using ubuntu and only plan to use ubuntu do they keep system accounts over 1000? Thanks for your reply

Comment: I'm actually not sure what Ubuntu's UID policies are.  That's pretty typical, though.

Comment: Second method is really good, just a quick question what is the purpose of the $3 variable how could u tell that its the 3rd parameter in a line?

Comment: Dont worry delimiters i just saw. Thank you so much. I accepted it because you explained :) and it was very quick

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any reliable way to do this.

Accounts for ordinary users commonly have uids greater than or equal to 1000, but that's only a convention. I've seen plenty of systems that don't follow that convention, and plenty of accounts that violate it, even on systems that try to follow it. And the `nobody` system account commonly has a uid like 65534.

Similarly, user accounts typically have gone directories under `/home`, but there are violations of that convention in both directions.

UNIX and UNIX-like systems make no firm distinction between user and system accounts (other than `root`).

The best you can do is to carefully examine the `/etc/passwd` file *on the system you're interested in*, and/or talk to the person in charge of creating accounts on that system, and try to derive some ad hoc rules -- and don't be surprised if a new account created tomorrow violates those rules. Someone a non-user account is created that deliberately acts like a user account, for testing purposes.

You might consider reformulating your requirements. Exactly what problem are you trying to solve?

One more thing: account information isn't always stored in `/etc/passwd`. Some systems use other mechanisms like NIS or LDAP. The `getent passwd` command (if your system has it) should allow for that.